# How to configure a Keycloak extensions developement environment?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, keycloak

I wish to extend Keycloak with few custom things (i.e. implementations of the `org.keycloak.authentication.RequiredActionsProvider` interface).

I'm strugging for a configuration for:

- produce DEBUG output
- eventually debug my implementation with my IDE (i.e. IntelliJIdea community)

I launch keycloak from in a docker container:

```yaml
version: '3.0'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${keycloak_version:-latest}
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: auth.lvh.me
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: Password1#
      DEBUG: true
      PRINT_ENV: true
    ports: [ "8080:8080", "8787:8787" ]
    command: [ "start-dev", "--log-level", "DEBUG",  "--debug" ]
    volumes:
      - ./target:/opt/keycloak/providers
    working_dir: /opt/keycloak
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - auth.lvh.me
```

and I use a basic `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lrkwz.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-required-actions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <keycloak.version>21.1.0</keycloak.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven-shade.version>3.2.4</maven-shade.version>
        <maven-surefire.version>3.0.0-M9</maven-surefire.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.dasniko</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-spi-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-shade.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.keycloak*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

As a result:

- NO environment is printed while KC starts up
- only ERROR level logging is shown as container output
- no way to attach the IDE debugger

I would also **like** to have a smoother development experience with my components *hot reload* while changing the code (presentely I need to `mvn package` + stop & start the container).

Reference:

1. https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging
2. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/quarkus/dist/src/main/content/bin/kc.sh

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that you use my customized `keycloak-spi-bom` ;)

Your `pom.xml` looks good, for your reference (if not already done so), see my example repository for Keycloak extensions: https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-extensions-demo

In my local Docker Compose environment, I also set the environment variable `DEBUG_PORT: '*:8787'`. This should be sufficient together with the `DEBUG: 'true'` env var. No need for `command` arguments.

For log-level, your CLI argument should work, however, I always use also the way via env vars, it's `KC_LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG`.

Regarding hot reload: bad news, since Quarkus there is no more hot-reloading possible. Unfortunately you'll have to restart the whole container after you re-built your JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dasniko pointing me in the right direction (and for the invaluable `keycloak-spi-bom`!).

The main problem here is the use of `auth.lvh.me`: the debug configuration trigger ONLY for `localhost`.

So `docker-compose.yml`should read:

```yaml
version: '3.0'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${keycloak_version:-latest}
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: Password1#
      DEBUG: true
      DEBUG_PORT: '*:8787'
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
    ports: [ "8080:8080", "8787:8787" ]
    command: [ "start-dev" ]
    volumes:
      - ./target:/opt/keycloak/providers
    working_dir: /opt/keycloak
```